# Как получить доступ из ArrayList к методам дочерних классов

Tags: java, классы, arraylist, типы

Как получить доступ из `ArrayList` к методам дочерних классов?

**Код:**

```
abstract  public class Solder  {
     private String name;
     private int healf;
     private int damage;
     private int armor;
     private int rangeAtack;
     public Solder(String name, int healf, int damage, int armor, int rangeAtack) {
         this.name = name;
         this.healf = healf;
         this.damage = damage;
         this.armor = armor;
         this.rangeAtack = rangeAtack;
     }

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }
     public int getHealf() {
         return healf;
     }
     public int getDamage() {
         return damage;
     }
     public int getArmor() {
         return armor;
     }
     public int getRangeAtack() {
         return rangeAtack;

     }

    public void setHealf(int healf) {
        this.healf = healf;
    }

    public void setDamage(int damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public void setArmor(int armor) {
        this.armor = armor;
    }

    public void setRangeAtack(int rangeAtack) {
        this.rangeAtack = rangeAtack;
    }
}

public  class Medic  extends  Solder {
    public Medic(String name, int healf, int damage, int armor, int rangeAtack) {
        super(name, healf, damage, armor, rangeAtack);
    }

    void Healing()
    {

    }
}

public class Sniper extends Solder{
    public Sniper(String name, int healf, int damage, int armor, int rangeAtack) {
        super(name, healf, damage, armor, rangeAtack);
    }
   
    public void SniperFier() {
      
        
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sniper sniper = new Sniper("Снайпер", 100, 300, 10, 100);
        Medic medic = new Medic("Медик", 350, 10, 20, 1);
        ArrayList<Solder>solders =new ArrayList<>();
        solders.add(medic);
        solders.add(sniper);
        solders.get(0).    // вот здесь нет доступа
}
```

Comment: "Не могу ..." - и не должны. Оно так работает. Если Вам нужно вызывать метод классa `Medic`, то и обращаться к объекту надо как к `Medic`, а не `Solder`. Правильно говорить - "Soldier".

Comment: А как тогда вызвать его что бы  не обращаться  medic.Healing(); А через  ArryList как то вот так soldier.get(1).Healing();

Comment: "как то вот так" - перечитайте мой первый комментарий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А через `ArryList` как то вот так

```
((Medic)solders.get(1)).Healing();
```

Comment: ((Medic)solders.get(1)).Healing(); это приведение типа ,а можно как то без приведения типа сделать что бы я брал из листа объект дочернего класс и мог бы получить доступ к его методам и полям  именно этого объекта get(i)

Comment: Вы не можете так сделать, потому что get(i) возвращает объект родительского класса. Поэтому приведение типа к дочернему классу.